# Use JavaScript to disable fields in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two fields in a HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="name1"/>
<input type="text" name="name2"/>
```

Is there a way using JavaScript that if the user user has entered text into the first test box, the second textbox is disabled and vice-versa?

Comment: Hint, try using the onBlur event this maybe possible. Try it out and let us know

Comment: you can add the attribute `disabled` to the input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an very simple example(jsfiddle link below):

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Name 1"/>
<input type="text" name="name2"id="name2" placeholder="Name 2"/>
```

---

```
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1'),
    name2 =document.getElementById('name2');

name1.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (name1.value.length > 0) {
    name2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    name2.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}

name2.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (name2.value.length > 0) {
    name1.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    name1.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Neviton/81zzjabk/

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with jQuery by disabling the input that wasn't being typed in using the [keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event in conjunction with the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method. That would look like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var textLength;
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    textLength = $(this).val().length;
    if (textLength > 0) {
       $('input').not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
       $('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name1"/>
<input type="text" name="name2"/>
```

Comment: What if you want to change which text box to use?

Comment: Just made an edit to address that @CharleyPearce let me know if it doesn't make sense and I will update my code to demonstrate it.

Comment: @CharleyPearce I just added the code to remove the `disabled` attribute if the user erases what they entered. Another option would be to create a "reset" button which would clear the value of either input and remove the `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery way:**

At first you have to create CSS class 'disabled'.

```
<style>
  .disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
```

Then you add event listener 'change' to your inputs.

```
  $( "input[value='name1']" ).change(function() {
    $("input[value='name2']" ).addClass('disabled');
  });
```

and

```
  $( "input[value='name2']" ).change(function() {
    $("input[value='name1']" ).addClass('disabled');
  });
```

That will do the trick. When user changes value of input it adds class 'disabled' to another input.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer in clear JavaScript. The advantage of using the disabled property is, that even with tabulating it is not possible to put an input into the other field.

In the snippet the disabling is also reset if both input fields are empty.

```js
var in1 = document.getElementById("input1"),
    in2 = document.getElementById("input2");

function doOnChange() {
  if (in1.value != "") {
    in1.disabled = false;
    in2.disabled = true;
  } else if (in2.value != "") {
    in1.disabled = true;
    in2.disabled = false;
  } if (in1.value == "" && in2.value == "") {
    in1.disabled = false;
    in2.disabled = false;
  }
}

in1.addEventListener("keyup", doOnChange);
in2.addEventListener("keyup", doOnChange);
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
<input id="input2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById('input1');
  var b = document.getElementById('input2');
  if (a.value.length == 0 && b.value.length == 0) {
    a.disabled = false;
    b.disabled = false;
  } else if (a.value.length == 0) {
    a.disabled = true;
  } else if (b.value.length == 0) {
    b.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
<input type="text" id="input2" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
```